# Does drawing the tentacle chaos token imply a failure with test result 0?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

Some tests result in penalties that increase with the level of failure in a test. For instance a willpower(3) test might say to lose a horror for each point you fail by. Would drawing tentacles mean failing by 3 points here regardless of how many points you started with, whether it be 8 or even -2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the tentacles token is an "automatic failure" for the skill test, which is defined on page 5 of the RRG:

> If a skill test automatically fails, the investigator’s total skill
>   value for that test is considered 0.

So in your example with a Willpower(3) test, revealing the tentacles would deal 3 horror.